# After update visual studio 2022 community, professional are showing different errors

Tags: package, visual-studio-2022, reinstall

Recently I have updated my visual studio 2022 to Version 17.7.4.
Update was successful but after that I getting following error

VC Project Cache error: Cannot establish connection to vcxprojreader.exe process: error code '80004005'.
Project cache will be unavailable and solution load might be slow.
Please reinstall Visual Studio and report this problem if it persists.

Also there is an popup which never came before,

[IntelliCodeCppPackage loading error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JpEqm.png)

Do I have to uninstall and reinstall visual studio mandatory? is there any failsafe workaround is there?

1. I tried to clear all cache, from folder
   C:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_XXXXX\ComponentModelCache folder.
2. I delete hidden .vs folder, and all .suo files in solution.
3. Tried to repair visual studio, spent 2 hours in it.
4. restarted system and visual studio multiple times.

Comment: You've tried all the things I'd recommend trying first, so I'd give it a reinstall.

Comment: Hi Timothy, thank you for suggestion, already started reinstall, will update if problem persists. Also created visual studio community question, so they know about this.

Comment: Hi, issue persists even after uninstall and reinstall.